# Create Parent Dictionary by key

Tags: python, dictionary, parent-child

I have a dicionary like this here:

```
example_dict = { 
    'key1' : 'value1',
    'key2' : 'value2',
    'key3' : 
    { 
        'key3a': 'value3a' 
    },
    'key4' : 
    { 
        'key4a': 
        { 
            'key4aa': 'value4aa',
            'key4ab': 'value4ab',
            'key4ac': 
            {
                'key4ac1': [0,1,2],
                'key4ac2': (3,4,5),
                'key4ac3': [
                    {
                        'sub_key_x': 0,
                        'sub_key_y': 1,
                    }, 
                    6
                ]               
            }
        },
        'key4b': 'value4b'
    }
}
```

I tried to create the parent dictionary using the recursive code of this question:
[Get parents keys from nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210148/get-parents-keys-from-nested-dictionary)

The problem are tuples or lists, which are breaking the loop.
I wanted to search strings in the dictionary, sorting the most matching results using difflib.

Would be really glad if anyone has an idea/schema how to search in the dictionary for the keys/values creating a parent dictionary.

for example:

```
search_in_dict(example_dict, 'sub key')
# returning the content of:
# example_dict['key4']['key4a']['key4ac']['key4ac3']
```

kind regards BaumKuchen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you want to do this, this type of thing will become slow when the data structure size increases. It would probably be better to have a flat dictionary, however the algorithm for flattening has to be defined.

I've done something crude for what I think you want. The `flatten` method returns something similar to `items` (a list of (key, value) tuples) where the 'key' is actually a tuple of keys. This is necessary as a dictionaries may contain the same key and so when transformed onto a flat namespace (which requires unique keys), a conflict arises.

```
class recurdict(dict):
    '''
    Recursive Dictionary
    '''
    def __init__(self, idict=None, **kwargs):
        dict.__init__(self)
        if idict is not None:
            self.update(idict)
        if len(kwargs):
            self.update(kwargs)

    def __contains__(self, key):
        return (key in self.keys())

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if self.__contains__(key):
            return self.___getitem__(self, key)
        else:
            raise KeyError(key)

    @staticmethod
    def ___getitem__(idict, key):
        if dict.__contains__(idict, key):
            return dict.__getitem__(idict, key) 
        else:
            result = None
            for k, v in idict.iteritems():
                if hasattr(v, "keys"):
                    result = recurdict.___getitem__(v, key)
                    if(result):
                        return result
                    else:
                        continue

    def flatten(self):
        return self._flatten(self)

    @staticmethod
    def _flatten(idict, key_chain = []):
        found_keys = []
        for k, v in idict.iteritems():
            if hasattr(v, "keys"):
                found_keys.extend(recurdict._flatten(v, key_chain + [k]))
            else:
                found_keys.append((tuple(key_chain + [k]), v))
        return found_keys

    def has_key(self, key):
        return self.__contains__(key)

    def keys(self):
        return self._keys(self)

    @staticmethod
    def _keys(idict):
        found_keys = dict.keys(idict)
        for k, v in idict.iteritems():
            if hasattr(v, "keys"):
                found_keys.extend(recurdict._keys(v))
        return found_keys

    def update(self, other=None, **kwargs):
        if other is None:
            pass
        elif hasattr(other, "iteritems"):
            for k, v in other.iteritems():
                self.__setitem__(k,v)
        elif hasattr(other, "keys"):
            for k in other.keys():
                self.__setitem__(k,other.__getitem__(k))
        else:
            for k, v in other:
                self.__setitem__(k,v)
        if kwargs:
            self.update(kwargs)

example_dict = recurdict\
({ 
    "key1" : "value1",
    "key2" : "value2",
    "key3" : 
    { 
        "key3a": "value3a" 
    },
    "key4" : 
    { 
        "key4a": 
        { 
            "key4aa": "value4aa",
            "key4ab": "value4ab",
            "key4ac": 
            {
                "key4ac1": [0,1,2],
                "key4ac2": (3,4,5),
                "key4ac3":
                [
                    {
                        "sub_key_x": 0,
                        "sub_key_y": 1,
                    }, 
                    6
                ]               
            }
        },
        "key4b": "value4b"
    }
})

print example_dict.keys()
print "key1" in example_dict
print "key4ac1" in example_dict
print example_dict["key4ac1"]
for (k, v) in example_dict.flatten():
    print (k, v)
```

Comment: thanks a lot, works good =)
To answer the question why I want this is, that I'm writing a script to maneuver through dictionaries(users select a key and get the content displayed,..), which works so far but I also wanted to implement a search function to find some keys/values faster.