# Find parent sibling in mixed dict/list

Tags: python, linux, dictionary, nested

I'd like to find the parent sibling in this array.

```
arr = {
    'children': [
        {
            'id':'item_1',
            'title':'Item 1',
            'children': [
                {
                    'id':'item_a',
                    'title':'Item A'
                },
                {
                    'id':'item_b',
                    'title':'Item B'
                },
                {
                    'id':'item_c',
                    'title':'Item C',
                    'children': [
                        {
                            'id':'item_i',
                            'title':'Item I'
                        },
                        {
                            'id':'item_ii',
                            'title':'Item II'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

For instance if I put "item_b" into the method it must return "item_1" (ignoring "children" as a parent). Something similar to this:

```
>>> parent = get_parent(arr, 'item_i', ['children'])
>>> parent['id']
item_c
>>> parent = get_parent(arr, 'item_1', ['children'])
>>> parent['id']
None
```

My id's are unique, so I know there will only ever be one parent.

I've looked at examples by [mgilson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15210253/1772200) and [Claudiu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31619360/1772200), but I can't get my head around how to change these to what I'm after. Claudius solution looks like the right direction, but with my array it just returns `[]`.

---

**Edit:**
ewcz solution works great. I modified it a bit to allow getting the title as well:

```
def get_parent(arr, item_id):
    L = [(None, arr)]
    while L:
        parent_item, item = L.pop()
        curr_id = item.get('id', None)
        if curr_id == item_id:
            return parent_item

        children = item.get('children', [])
        for child in children:
            L.append((item, child))

parent = get_parent(arr, 'item_i')
print(parent.get('id'))
print(parent.get('title'))
```

Comment: Are you sure about the "sibling" word in title? From the description it looks like you only want the parent items. Sibling items would be those that share a parent, like `item_i` and `item_ii` in your example.

Comment: @gereleth You might be right, but I was thinking `id` and `title` are siblings to `children`.

Comment: I recently learned about the a* algorithm and now I see that @ewcz code is very similar to the algorithm. Just thought this might help any googlers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one option would be to traverse your array and return the parent id as soon as the traversal hits the item of interest:

```
def get_parent(arr, item_id):
    L = [(None, arr)]
    while L:
        parent_id, item = L.pop()

        curr_id = item.get('id', None)
        if curr_id == item_id:
            return parent_id

        children = item.get('children', [])
        for child in children:
            L.append((curr_id, child))

parent = get_parent(arr, 'item_i')
```

Comment: Thanks! See modified solution in my post.

Comment: @NinjaFart my pleasure, although I think that the modification will give you directly the element with the specified id, not its parent...

Comment: Ups, you are correct. I've updated my post - should work now.